# How does one solve the equation $3^x+5\cdot3^x\cdot2^x-2^x=0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

I've tried to solve equations
$$3^x+5\cdot3^x\cdot2^x-2^x=0$$ $$81^x−2·54^x−36^x−2·24^x+16^x=0$$
 but I failed.

I don't know where to start. Any help is welcome

Comment: Can you rewrite $81^x$ in terms of $3^x$ ?

Comment: Do you need integer solutions? real solutions?

Comment: For the first one, try dividing by $2^x 3^x$.

Comment: @user321670 I think it was never said that this was a system of equations

Comment: Are the two equations to be solved simultaneously?

Comment: @Wore looking at the first equality x should be less than 1..hence not integer solutions

Comment: There could be a negative integer solution for $x$ in the first equation ... .

Comment: For the first equation, $x=-2$

Comment: @DavidQuinn how to get it or how to prove that for $$x>-2$$ and $$x<-2$$ equation have not solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second equation can be solved by dividing every term by $16^x$ and substituting $$u=\left(\frac 32\right)^x$$
Then we have to solve the equation $$u^4-2u^3-u^2-2u+1=0$$
$$\Rightarrow (u^2-3u+1)(u^2+u+1)=0$$

So the real solutions are given by $$u=\frac {3\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}$$ from which you can deduce the values of $x$

Answer (score 1):

I am going to go ahead and finish up Equation 1.

Having identified one solution $x=-2$, prove it is unique among the reals.

Divide the equation by $2^x$ and move the last, now constant term, to the RHS:

$(3/2)^x+5(3^x)=1$

The LHS is strictly monotonic for all real $x$ so there can be only the one solution.

On to Eq. 2.  Hint:  There are no rational solutions, yet all solutions can be expressed with elementary functions only.  Enjoy!